# How to store a non-native table in orc format in HIVE?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

Is it possible to store a non-native table in ORC file format in a hive?
If yes, how?

I am using Hive 1.1.0

```
hive>create external table test1(id int,name string)
clustered by (id) into 2 buckets
stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
with serdeproperties("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,cf1:name")
tblproperties('transactional'='true','hbase.table.name'='test1');

hive>alter table test1 set fileformat orc;
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10134]: ALTER TABLE cannot be used for a non-native table test1

Comment: Hbase data is not represented the same as Hive. Therefore this doesn't exactly make sense

Comment: I'm trying to integrate hbase and hive and i want to do crud operations.So in order to be able to do update and delete I must set the fileformat to orc.

Comment: If you want SQL queries over Hbase, most people use Phoenix, not Hive